# The Select query I am using is not working.. Can Somebody Guide me to the Correct way?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the Select query as

```
SELECT id, ordering FROM `jos_menu` WHERE ordering='".$rec['ordering'] -'1' ."' AND parent = '0'
```

Here I need all the records whose ordering is less than 1 of the selected record's order(`$rec['ordering'] = getting from other select query` )  when I am trying to echo the query I am not getting complete statement but getting only this `-1' AND parent = '0'`

here is the whole snippet

```
$where = ' WHERE (id = ' . implode( ' OR id = ', $cid ) . ')';//Pranav Dave Coded
    echo $selquery = "SELECT id, ordering FROM `jos_menu`".$where;          //Pranav Dave Coded
        $db->setQuery( $selquery );//Pranav Dave Coded
        $record = $db->loadAssocList(); //Pranav Dave Coded

    if ($model->orderItem($id, -1)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($model);
    /*exit;*/

    //echo $updorderup = mysql_escape_string($model->_db->_sql);//Pranav Dave Coded

        foreach($record as $rec)//Pranav Dave Coded
        {
            echo $aboverow = "SELECT id, ordering FROM `jos_menu` WHERE ordering='".$rec['ordering'] -'1' ."' AND parent = '0'";
            $db->setQuery( $aboverow );
        $above = $db->loadAssoc();
        echo "<pre>";
    print_r($above);
                    }//end of foreach
                 }//end of if
```

Please suggest me where I am getting wrong.....

Comment: first of all do separate matters. if you have SQL query problem - bring here query itself, not PHP code. why do you print queries for yourself, bot not bring it here?

Comment: or its PHP code not working, not SQL query? Can you be more clear? if you have ordering='-1' from the ordering='".$rec['ordering'] -'1' $rec['ordering'] is just empty. isn't it just obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to unwrap the `-1` from the quotes:

```
WHERE ordering='".($rec['ordering'] - 1)."' AND parent = '0'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you trying to put everything inline?
Why not to make some preparations first?
Why not to compare resulting query with sample one?
Why don't you check every step if it return proper result?

```
$val = $rec['ordering'] - 1;
//let's see if $cal has proper value:
echo $val."<br>";
$sql = "SELECT id, ordering FROM `jos_menu` WHERE ordering = $val AND parent = 0";
//let's see if query looks good:
echo $sql;
//let's print sampe query to compare:
echo "<br>" ;
echo "SELECT id, ordering FROM `jos_menu` WHERE ordering = 1 AND parent = 0";
```

Comment: Why DO U Ask SO Much WHY?? Are U a Coder Or Cornell or Lawyer?

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, you need to remove the quotes around the -1. Currently its trying to minus a string, which it wouldn't be happy with at all ;)

Comment: oh, really? ever heard of PHP type casting?

Comment: Of course I've heard of it, but it doesn't change the fact that taking 1 in that way doesn't work (I've just ran a series of tests to prove it).

You should do all your math outside of the SQL query Parth, when I tried to remove 1 (as an int) inline like that I got a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error. 

Let us know if thats sorts your problems.